# Power Transistor Help

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I'm looking to switch an 18v signal at 1 amp with a N-Channel power MOSFET with at least 1.5v to turn it on in a TO-220 package but unfortunately I've only been able to find this one from Fairchild:

https://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FD/FDD9409_F085.html

This one would work but what I'm concerned about is efficiency. Would this one be fine on efficiency even though I'm looking to only switch an 18v signal or should I keep looking? If I should look for a different one, can anyone suggest a N-Channel power MOSFET in a TO-220 package that would be better?

Comment: Please specify the package more closely. TO what? TO220? TO251? TO252? TO262? TO263? And do you need N-type or P-type? You've suggested an N-type, but maybe you missed the distinction. How much current do you need? What sort of drive are you looking to supply - 2 volts, 3.3 volts, 5 volts?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Sorry for the vague description, I've edited it with the updated information.

Answer (score 1):

What are your power requirements? Looking at the datasheet for that MOSFET:

[image]

I really depends on the voltage you will apply to the MOSFET while it is switching. This particular device has a 150W power rating, so you have plenty of room unless you are passing high current.

If you are planning on switching this MOSFET with some kind of microcontroller then you should consider the Vgs that you will be applying (5V is shown as the bottom curve of the above plot.

> N-Channel power MOSFET with at least 1.5v to turn it on

This particular model has a Vgs threshold of 4V.

For more elaborate help you should consider posting a schematic.

Comment: Do you think this one will work better based on the description?https://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FD/FDD3706.html

Comment: The first one has better thermal resistances, so it won't dissipate as much heat. The device you just posted has about 1/3 the power rating as the other one as well. Again, it really depends on your application. If you look at figure 1 on page 3 of the datasheet you just posted you can see the Vds for a particular Vgs and drain current. What are you switching ?

Comment: So that I answer your question properly, what type of responses are you looking for when you ask what I'm switching?

Comment: [Like this](http://images.elektroda.net/27_1345134574.gif). Are you driving some kind of high-power LED, a motor, a light .. etc.

Comment: I'm switching 18v for turning on another transistor on a separate device attached to the transistor that we're talking about. But first the voltage in runs through a microcontroller so that's why there's a low voltage available to feed into the gate. (If I need to clarify, just ask but I can't figure out how to post a schematic)

Comment: There's not a lot of current draw on the device that I'm switching if that's why you were asking.

Comment: If you are just using the MOSFET to switch on another MOSFET then the devices you have posted are way overkill. To post a schematic you can hit the editor button when you edit your post. You can build the schematic using discrete components and then it will automatically link to your post once you publish it.

Comment: Should I use a relay instead then? Or is there something else that I should do like use a BJT instead of a MOSFET?

Answer (score 0):

Go to digikey.com, product listings, Discrete Semiconductors, FETs (single). Select package type TO220AB, rank by increasing Vgs(th). There are two pages of TO220 MOSFETs with gate threshold of ~1 volt or less.